# usermod cannot lock /etc/passwd when usermod is in /etc/sudoers as NOPASSWD

Tags: linux, usermod

Need to be able to execute 'usermod' without sudo, so that a script on a remote machine may disable and lock a userid on the instance host.

Adding 'nopasswd' and the command to the wheel group in sudoers on the instance host should work, if I'm reading the sudoers documentation correctly.

Have added `%wheel  ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/usermod` via visudo to /etc/sudoers on the host:

Then running the command results in failure:

```
username@hostname:21:21:20 UTC - ~ $ usermod --expiredate 1 --lock $uid
usermod: Permission denied.
usermod: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
```

Note that 'username' in the block above is a member of wheel, and that running 'sudo usermod....' does work.

Have also tried `%wheel  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/usermod` with the same failure.

Is there a method to fix/workaround the permission/lock issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you still need to use `sudo` to run the command, you just won't be prompted for the password.

With this you could probably include `sudo` in your remote command depending on how you have all this configured. You don't need to worry about `sudo` doing anything else since your explicitly stating `nopasswd` for only the `usermod` tool

Comment: Thanks, Tim. via ```ssh -n <hostname> sudo usermod --expiredate 1 --lock <username>``` gets the 'ssh: no tty present and not askpass....' error

Comment: I've gotten around this issue by ```ssh -t ....```